# ColSum of Characters

Tags: r, col

I'm looking to create a total column that counts the number of cells in a particular row that contains a character value. The values will only be 1 of 3 different letters (R or B or D). So using the example from the script below, outcomes will be: `p1=`2, `p2=1`, `p3=2`, `p4=1`, `p5=1`

I'm thinking using `nrow` with a condition would be the way to go, but I'm unable to get that to work. Something like this:

```
# count the number of columns where the cell is not blank (or contains an R,B,D)
test$tot <- nrow(!test="")
```

Any help is much appreciated!

---------------- script for reference:

```
  column1 <- c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5")
  column2 <- c("R","","R","R","")
  column3 <- c("","B","","","B")
  column4 <- c("D","","D","","")
  test <- data.frame(column1,column2,column3,column4)
  colnames(test)[c(1:4)] <- c("pol_nbr","r1","r2","r3")
  View(test)
```

Comment: `rowSums(test[-1] != "")`.

Comment: This seems to be including an extra column in the sum? test$tot_cols <- rowSums(test[,-1] != "")

Comment: `test[-1]` is the same has `test[, -1]`. But do whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rowSums`:

```
test$tot_cols <- rowSums(test[, -1] != "")
```

Comment: For some reason this is still giving me an outcome with an additional count. Eg: p1 = 3, when it should be 2. It's an exact copy of the code above

Comment: Perhaps you're running it on a data frame where you've already added another column? Try specifying the columns to include rather than the columns to not include, `rowSums(test[, paste0("r", 1:3)] != "")`

Comment: Oh man, you're exactly right, that was it.. I had an extra column in there. Appreciate you working through it with me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Converts factors to characters and use nzchar():

```
test <- data.frame(column1, column2, column3, column4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test$ne <- rowSums(apply(test[-1], 2, nzchar))
test
  column1 column2 column3 column4 ne
1      p1       R               D  2
2      p2               B          1
3      p3       R               D  2
4      p4       R                  1
5      p5               B          1
```

Comment: Gregor's solution is faster